# UEC store error

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, cloud-storage, eucalyptus

I installed UEC with the help of this [manual](http://cssoss.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/eucabookv2-0.pdf).
And and I had not any problems until I tried to enter the section Store in Web-interface. At this point, get error messages:

```
Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [thread on Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1837612) talking about this problem.

So far there is no real "good" solution.

You can :

1. Change the `imagestore/lib/fetch.py` source file in order to disable verification of remote image store server (see message #6 on the ubuntuforums thread)
2. Rebuild/Reinstall `python-pycurl` using `libopenssl` rather than `libgnutls` (see [that bug report on debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515200#15))

Comment: Thanks, it realy works, but I found answer two months ago.